# Determining what was being dragged inside dragLeaveEvent

Tags: c++, qt

How can I detect what is being dragged while in:

```
void dragLeaveEvent(QDragLeaveEvent *event);
```

Thanks.

Comment: Afaik, you need to get that information from the QDragEnterEvent preceeding it.

Comment: @Mat because I'd like to know what is being dragged at the moment of leaving.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After confirming my memory with the documentation, [`QDragLeaveEvent`](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qdragleaveevent.html) carries no information on the dragged item, the documentation states though;

> This event is always preceded by a QDragEnterEvent and a series of QDragMoveEvents.

[`QDragEnterEvent`](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qdragenterevent.html) carries all the information you need, you'll need to save that information if you need to use it when the `QDragLeaveEvent` arrives.